# need excel function for this issue

Tags: excel, vba

I have table with name and no. but every name have more than one no. in the same cell if i want to make every no with its name in separate cell with function how can i do that

Example,

h1  "113
333
354
323"
"
I want to make like below with function 
h1  113
h1  333
h1  354
h1  323

or you can download the Example sheet from below link

[MY example Sheet](http://www.4shared.com/file/fM81FaS6ce/Book4.html?)

Please Help me Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working code of a VBA function that fits your needs:

```
Sub RedistributeData()
  Dim X As Long, LastRow As Long, A As Range, Table As Range, Data() As String
  Const Delimiter As String = vbLf
  Const DelimitedColumn As String = "B"
  Const TableColumns As String = "A:B"
  Const StartRow As Long = 1
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  LastRow = Columns(TableColumns).Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlFormulas).Row
  For X = LastRow To StartRow Step -1
    Data = Split(Cells(X, DelimitedColumn), Delimiter)
    If UBound(Data) > 0 Then
      Intersect(Rows(X + 1), Columns(TableColumns)).Resize(UBound(Data)).Insert xlShiftDown
    End If
    If Len(Cells(X, DelimitedColumn)) Then
      Cells(X, DelimitedColumn).Resize(UBound(Data) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Data)
    End If
  Next
  LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, DelimitedColumn).End(xlUp).Row
  On Error Resume Next
  Set Table = Intersect(Columns(TableColumns), Rows(StartRow).Resize(LastRow - StartRow + 1))
  If Err.Number = 0 Then
    Table.SpecialCells(xlBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
    Columns(DelimitedColumn).SpecialCells(xlFormulas).Clear
    Table.Value = Table.Value
  End If
  On Error GoTo 0
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I reworked it from [this example](http://www.excelfox.com/forum/f22/redistribute-a-delimited-column-of-data-into-separate-rows-keeping-other-data-as-is-420/).

Comment: Thank you v. much its worked v. good but can you advice me if i can replace the "," with new line

Comment: The code I posted above splits on new line, not comma. See here:
`Const Delimiter As String = vbLf`

Comment: Can I reverse this function please?